# Why frozen and locked topics becomes community wiki

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, community-wiki

So here is what the locked and closed question banner say.

Locked questions:

> **locked** by `<username>`♦ `<date>` at `<time>`
>
> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it **is
>   not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do
>   not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This
>   question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info:
>   [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help).

Closed questions:

> **closed** as `<blah blah>` by `<username>`♦ `<date>` at `<date>`
>
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A
>   format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or
>   expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments,
>   polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be
>   improved and possibly reopened, [visit the help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) for guidance.
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions),
>   please edit the question or leave a comment.

Probably some of the most loathing notification for the asker.

So moderator lock a particular question because the question is not considered a good, on-topic question for the given SE site then why locking the question transfers the question in community wiki? I mean I used to thought that community wiki have a collection of good questions.

Comment: Actually community wiki status is often (but not always) an indicator of a _bad_ question for this site.

Answer (score 5):

The `locked` and `community wiki` status of a question are completely independent, and it is perfectly possible for a post to be locked without being community wiki. An example of this is

- [Creating an ammeter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/creating-an-ammeter) (currently locked and attributed to [MathsStudent](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/3044/mathsstudent)).

On the other hand, this doesn't mean that they're not *correlated*, and it is indeed true that many posts which are locked are also community wiki. A good way to see this is to [google the lock banner text for this site](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=This%20question%20exists%20because%20it%20has%20historical%20significance%2C%20but%20it%20is%20not%20considered%20a%20good%2C%20on-topic%20question%20for%20this%20site%20site%3Aphysics.stackexchange.com#q=This+question+exists+because+it+has+historical+significance%2C+but+it+is+not+considered+a+good%2C+on-topic+question+for+this+site+site%3Aphysics.stackexchange.com). There are indeed a lot of such results; on example is

- [Books that every layman should read](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13020/books-that-every-layman-should-read) (currently locked and community wiki).

The reason for this is that 'big-list' questions were indeed allowed early in this site's history. However, they generate a lot of hits and therefore a lot of reputation for answers which may in themselves not be really that valuable (i.e. their main merit is being posted in the right thread at the right time), with the addition of a large snowball effect. This was deemed undesirable so most of these threads were put on community wiki.

Later on, though, big-list posts were deemed off-topic, which is still the policy today. (Roughly, it's because those posts are the fast food of Q&A sites. They're entertaining for a while but they're perennially active and they detract attention from more valuable threads.) Closing them is a bad half-measure because edits can keep them active. Deleting them is too much because they do have valuable content. Hence they were put on historical lock.

---

Other than that, your question is a bit confusing and it's hard to know what you mean without the specific examples that made you ask this.